# Strange view of Eclipse in Android 1.5

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to create Android 1.5 app, but suddenly after update Android SDK I found that Android 1.5 and 1.6 projects look like below (clear activity with button - nothing more):

[image]
At the same time new Android 2.1 project looks like as usual:

[image]

So, is it normal view in Eclipse or I have to fix something ?

Comment: Just a curiosity, why are you creating for an Android version that is basically deprecated?

Comment: The reason is very simple - I need to support the apps for devices, which never get the update to Android 4.0.

Comment: I understand your point and I agree that as developers we must keep compatibility back  to older devices,  but my point is http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html there're virtually no 1.5 around anymore. Developing on 1.5 you'll only be creating problems for yourself with no real increase in downloads. The improvements that happened on Donut make it very compelling to ditch 1.5 without looking back. E.g. I work in one of the major UK app developing agencies and their development base is API8 (Froyo).